# Can I display Media Videos in a single "media player" block

Tags: files, media

I have several youtube videos listed on a page. I am currently loading them as Media Fields. What I would like to do is declare a single block (or perhaps a region) where the videos play no matter which video I select. SO rather than displaying the URL to a video, or the video itself, I want to display a play button.

Is there a standard way of doing this with Media, or do I have to create my own Javascript to insert the video into a "video player" block

Answer (score 1):

You could create a View that makes a Block, and set it to display videos that meet whichever criteria. Or, you can just embed videos directly in a block with `embed` code. You can try the [Video](http://drupal.org/project/video) module or [Video Embed Field](http://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) to show videos from another source or from your side.

Answer (score 0):

I think using [embedded media field](http://drupal.org/project/emfield) and [media youtube](http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube) modules will do.you have to create a block view of the respective media field content type.We have options either to display thumbnail or full video images.